# Folding Curried Functions in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Applying an argument list to curried function using foldLeft in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606587/applying-an-argument-list-to-curried-function-using-foldleft-in-scala)

Consider:

```
val f = (i: Int, j: Int, k: Int, l: Int) => i + j + k + l
```

Because one can do this:

```
f.curried.apply(1).apply(2).apply(3).apply(4)
```

It's easy to fall into the trap of trying this:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4).foldLeft(f.curried) { (fs, e) => fs.apply(e) }
```

However, the `B` parameter in the fold changes type once one applies an argument to it. In this example, the first iteration would change from a `(Int) => (Int) => (Int) => (Int) => Int` to a `(Int) => (Int) => (Int) => Int`.

Question: How to solve this?

Comment: I don't think this makes sense. In `(fs, e) => fs.apply(e)` you are actually using a different type for `fs` on every iteration and it's a different `apply` function. I don't see how it could work.

Comment: I think the problem is that it's not entirely clear what is being looked for here. The problem suggested in the title - folding curried functions - is never going to work because of the problem you identify. So what's the underlying problem? Applying a list of parameters to a function?

Comment: This was discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606587/applying-an-argument-list-to-curried-function-using-foldleft-in-scala).

Comment: This is a duplicate; please, vote close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with an HList - see http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/07/08/type-level-programming-in-scala-part-6b-hlist%C2%A0folds/ for an example of building fold functions over heterogenous lists.

Edit -  hbatista's link in the comment above provides a full solution doing precisely this.