# Pass list as individual function parameters

Tags: scala

I have a function `def f(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int, ...)` and I'd like to supply a list of consecutive integers as parameters (in a unit test).

Is there a neat way to supply `(1 to N).toList` to `f`? Since the function is not `def f(x: Int*`) I cannot simply use `list: _*` with `list` the list of integers.

Comment: Writing as a comment since it's not a full-blown answer, but might take you on the right path: you can curry your function to make it `Int => Int => Int => Int => Int`, and then take your list of integers and keep (partially) applying them one by one to the function via `foldLeft`. 

This question goes into details of that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606587/applying-an-argument-list-to-curried-function-using-foldleft-in-scala  
  
If you had a tuple instead of a list, you could apply it to `f.tupled`, but if you do have a list then forget that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in standard Scala in a typesafe way, but it's possible to do it using the [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) library. Even if you don't use this library in the project, you can depend on it only for the test scope.

Here is the code sample:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.function._
import shapeless.ops.traversable._

def applyToList[F, HL <: HList, R](f: F)(args: List[Any])(implicit
  // convert `(T1, T2, ...) => R` to a function from a single HList argument `HL => R`
  fnToProduct: FnToProduct.Aux[F, HL => R],  
  // convert the argument list to the HList, expected by the converted function
  toHList: FromTraversable[HL]
): R = {
  toHList(args) match {
    case Some(hargs) => fnToProduct(f)(hargs)
    case None => sys.error("argument list not applicable to function")
  }
}
```

Using it is as simple as this:

```
def f(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int): Any = ???
applyToList(f _)(List(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

But notice the need for an explicit eta-conversion `f _`, because the Scala compiler doesn't really know, that `F` is a function.

You can change the definition to return `Option[R]`, because it's impossible to know at compile-time if the provided `List` will fit the function or not. For example, the argument list may have a non-matching number of elements. But if this is for unit-tests, you may as well just throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify `f()` then you're kinda stuck. One (not terrific) thing you could do is write an implicit translator.

Let's pretend that `f()` takes 4 `Int` args.

```
implicit class Caller4[A,R](func: (A,A,A,A)=>R) {
  def call(as :A*) :R = func(as(0),as(1),as(2),as(3))
}

(f _).call(1 to 4:_*)    //call f(1,2,3,4)
```

The good new is that this will work for any/all methods that take 4 parameters of the same type.

The bad news is that you need a different translator for every required arity, and the compiler won't catch it if you invoke `call()` with too few parameters.